# Need help removing middle element in an array if the length is odd, or the middle two if its even

Tags: java, arrays

Basically, one of my assignments is if the array is odd, remove the middle element or if the array is even, remove the middle two elements.

Here is my code, it may be sloppy  as this is my first year of high school Java.

```
 public static void removeMiddle(int[] arr)
 {
     int size = arr.length;
     if(size % 2 ==0)
     {
         int x = arr.length/2 -1;
         for(int i = x; i <= arr.length - 2; i++)
         {   
             arr[i] = arr[i + 2];
         }
     }
     else
     {
         int z = arr.length/2;
         for(int i = z; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
         {
             arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
         }
     }
 }
```

I was following the pseudo code that the teacher gave us if we got stuck. When I'm running it, it's adding an extra element.

For example, my array 3, 6, -2, 8, 9 changes to 3, 6, 8, 9, 9, after running it

1. Create a local variable named "size" that stores the length of the array passed in.

   ```
   * 2.  If the size of the array happens to be even, do the following:
   *   a.  Create a local variable that represents the first to remove by assigning it to be one less than
   *       half the size of the array
   *   b.  Run a for-loop starting at the value you just calculated (representing the first to remove) and
   *       terminating at two less than the size of the array
   *       i.  In the for-loop, assign the value at the current index of the array to be the value at two
   *           more than the current index
   * 3.  Otherwise, given the size of the array happens to be odd, do the following:
   *   a.  Create a local variable that represents the first to remove by assigning it to be half the 
   *       size of the array
   *   b.  Run a for-loop starting at the value you just calculated (representing the first to remove) and
   *       terminating at one less than the size of the array
   *       i.  In the for-loop, assign the value at the current index of the array to be the value at one 
   *           more than the current index
   ```

Any suggestions?

Comment: java.util.Arrays,copyOfRange() rules! :-)

Comment: looking at the "instructions" you are basically just shifting the numbers in the array from the middle by on or two to the left?
ie.: input 1,2,3,4,5 would end up 1,2,4,5,5?

Comment: You are getting the result because you are not changing the size of array and not removing the last element after shifting. You can create a new array of size length -1 in case of odd length and of size lingth-2 in case of even length array and copy the array.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understood your questions correctly.

Is it saying, for example, if an array had the size of 8 (8 elements),
the new array returned after the method should return a new array with 6 elements?

I would first, change the return type of the method you provided to be int[].

You can try to implement stack, or queue, or simply stick to using arrays with a bunch of conditionals.

```
int size = arr.length;
int newArr[];
if(size % 2 ==0) {
    newArr = new int[size-2];
    for (int i = 0; i < (newArr.length/2); i++) {
        newArr[i] = arr[i];
        System.out.println(newArr[i]);
    }
    for (int i = (newArr.length/2); i < newArr.length; i++) {
        newArr[i] = arr[i+2];
        System.out.println(newArr[i]);
    }
}
else {
    newArr = new int[size-1];
    for(int i = 0; i < (newArr.length/2); i++) {
        newArr[i] = arr[i];
        System.out.println(newArr[i]);
    }
    for (int i = (newArr.length/2); i < newArr.length; i++) {
        newArr[i] = arr[i+1];
        System.out.println(newArr[i]);
    }
}
```

if the input was 123456, this produces 1256
if the input was 12345, this produces 1245

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, in the "even" if clause, you should just change the

```
for(int i = x; i <= arr.length - 2; i++)
```

to

```
for(int i = x; i < arr.length - 2; i++)
```

Do you need to get from 1,2,3,4,5,6 an array like 1,2,5,6,5,6 or 1,2,5,6?

Comment: I would need to get it to 1, 2, 5, 6

Answer (score 0):

To delete the elements from an array, you need to make a new array from the  existing one, and then return the result, or change the reference of the original array to the new created array.

```
public static void removeMiddle(int[] myArray)
        {
            int size = myArray.length;
            int[] resultArray;
            if(size % 2 ==0)
            {
                resultArray = new int [myArray.length-2];
            }
            else
            {
                 resultArray = new int [myArray.length-1];

            }
            int mid1 =  myArray.length/2;
            int mid2 = myArray.length/2 - 1;
            int index = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
            {
                if(size % 2 ==0 && (i==mid1 || i==mid2))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else if(!((size % 2) ==0) && i==mid1)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                resultArray[index] = myArray[i];
                index++;
            }

            for(int i=0;i<resultArray.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("array[" + i + "] = " + resultArray[i]);
            }
        }
```

If myArray hold the value as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 the output will be as below

```
array[0] = 1
array[1] = 2
array[2] = 3
array[3] = 5
array[4] = 6
array[5] = 7
```

and if it hole the value as 1,2,3,4,5,6 the output will be as below

```
array[0] = 1
array[1] = 2
array[2] = 5
array[3] = 6
```